# How is the OperationContractAttribute.Action value is set?

Tags: wsdl, service-reference, operationcontract

I'm using the "Add Service Reference" option in Visual Studio in order to create a proxy class using a WSDL file given to me by a third party.
I got 2 versions of the WSDL - we'll call them "OLD" and "NEW".

Even though the WSDL files suppose to be the same (the new one got updated methods version) , when creating the proxy classes I get a different values in the OperationContractAttribute.Action.

In the OLD wsdl it looks like that:

```
[System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://webservices.amadeus.com/SATRQT_13_2_1A", ReplyAction="*")]
```

In the new wsdl it looks like that:

```
[System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://xml.amadeus.com/AmadeusWebServicesPT/Air_MultiAvailabilityRequest", ReplyAction="http://xml.amadeus.com/AmadeusWebServicesPT/Air_MultiAvailabilityResponse")]
```

I can't figure it out from where the "Action" value is taken from.

In the old WSDL the value is valid , but in the new WSDL is completely wrong and I get an exception when trying to use the service in the WS

When I look in the OLD wsdl file i can see a "soapAction" with the same value; this seems to be where it's taken from. However in the NEW wsdl there is a value there exactly like in the OLD wsdl

```
<wsdl:operation name="Air_MultiAvailability">
  <soap:operation soapAction="http://webservices.amadeus.com/SATRQT_13_2_1A" />
```

Can anyone direct to me to the right place?

### Update

After reading some more on the "Action" element I realized that the value that I see in the NEW wsdl is the DEFAULT value (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.operationcontractattribute.action(v=vs.110).aspx)

Now I need to understand WHY in the OLD wsdl file we get the Action value to be the correct one (I'm guessing from the *soapAction* defined in the wsdl file under the correct operation) and in the NEW wsdl there is no match and a default value is populated ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ok found the problem!

in the WSDL file there were multiple "Operation" with the same name

```
<wsdl:portType name="WebServices"> 
  <wsdl:operation name="DoSomething">
      <wsdl:input message="ns:DoSomething_1_1" />
      <wsdl:output message="ns:DoSomething_1_1" />
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="DoSomething">
      <wsdl:input message="ns:DoSomething_2_2" />
      <wsdl:output message="ns:DoSomething_2_2" />
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>

<wsdl:binding type="ns:WebServices" name="WebServicesBinding">
    <wsdl:operation name="DoSomething">
      <soap:operation soapAction="http://webservices.my.com/DoSomething_1_1" />
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="DoSomething">
      <soap:operation soapAction="http://webservices.my.com/DoSomething_2_2" />
    </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
```

the "DoSomething" got 2 version in this example 1.1 and 2.2
once i deleted\renamed ALL duplicated operations (i had multiple of them) the "Action" value was taken from the "soapAction" element

hope this will help someone in the future !